# How to use the weapon-wheel with a mouse?

Tags: pc, watch-dogs

I'm playing the first mission in watch_dogs on PC and it asks me to graft a distraction and throw it onto the wall when hiding behind a desk.

However, the weapon wheel is incredibly difficult to select the right option from with a mouse. I'm guessing it's made for a thumbstick where you can rotate the thumbstick to select an option. However with no cursor, when I move the mouse around, the weapon wheel seemingly jumps randomly to different options.

How can I control the weapon wheel accurately to select the option I want easily, every time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to move the mouse in a circular motion to cycle through all the equipment available, just like a thumbstick. The scroll wheel up or down select the weapons in their slots. Alternatively you can use the arrow keys to cycle through the equipment and select the weapons.

Comment: Ugh, that's what I was afraid the answer would be (circular motion) - very hard with a sensitive mouse. Arrow keys sounds interesting, but involves taking the hand off the mouse. Maybe I can bind two of the function buttons on the mouse the the arrow keys...

Comment: If your mouse has extra buttons I suppose you can bind them as an alternative to the weapon hotkeys (1 to 4) and the equipments hotkey (5).

Comment: Two weeks in and I've basically given up on the weapon wheel. I just use keys 1-5 for the basic weapons, use whatever's in the default spot (although I make sure the silenced pistol is always in #2) almost never switch weapons, and typically don't use crafted items or grenades unless I really have to. I find sneaking way more satisfying anyway.

Comment: I got used to it, after some time, but it still doesn't feel quite right. All the in-game menus seem to be designed for a gamepad, rather than a mouse and keyboard. It really seems that the devs didn't put much effort in the port as they should have. I also prefer the stealth approach, especially knocking out enemies with the baton, even though the game doesn't seem to reward you any better for [that](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/172356/differences-in-lethal-vs-non-lethal-completion-of-missions).

Comment: Circular motion?  I just move the mouse in the direction of the option I want...