# Differences in Lethal vs Non-Lethal completion of missions?

Tags: watch-dogs

I have played the game completely through and I am wondering if there is any difference in the way you complete a mission. If you do it completely unseen do you get any sort of offset in XP for all the missed take downs knock downs? Does it have any impact on the story line like

> Does it alter the scene where you save Jacks and he sees you kill all those people if you did not kill them?

I guess I am wondering if there is any replay added to the game other than personal challenge if I were to try a completely stealth/knock down only play through vs my last one where leaving people standing just appeared to give me less XP.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170063

Comment: First ever time you break into a ctOS station, the mission ends with "I better get out of here, I made a lot of noise" (or something like that). I didn't make any noise; I didn't even enter the premises. Did the whole thing via cameras. It was then I realised that you are not rewarded for stealth, like you are in Deus Ex.

Comment: Story wise it doesn't make any difference whatsoever, but in some cases, going stealth can award you with extra reputation.

Answer (score 3):

From personal experience and from scrounging around the internet I come to this conclusion:

It does not matter if you kill everything in sight or knock them out with your baton. It also doesn't reward you with extra XP, if you go unseen and don't touch anyone (I think you even miss XP, if you do missions that way).

The story is pretty much scripted.

> Saving Jack non-lethally [doesn't change anything](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/704529-watch-dogs/69350257). The same cut-scene rolls anyway, so just go guns blazing.

Comment: That coincides with what I have seen so far as well.

Comment: I did a "takedown" on someone in that mission, attempting to achieve the same outcome non-lethally. Aiden proceeded to use his baton to kneecap the dude, then shot him in the face with a silenced pistol anyway. Great.

Comment: @MarkHenderson: That will happen if you have a weapon equipped.