# What is the advantage of playing non-lethally?

Tags: watch-dogs

Going through Watch_Dogs (currently at the start of act 2) I've mostly been sneaking around and punching people unconscious to deal with enemies and gang hideouts. However, this has become progressively more difficult to do so without being spotted, so I've started to consider to shoot hostiles with the silenced pistol one by one until they're gone.

I am wondering though, does engaging in non-lethal takedowns net me more XP than just shooting them in the face? If so, how large is this difference? And does it make a difference if they know you're there or not?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Watch_Dogs wiki](http://watchdogs.wikia.com/wiki/Takedown):

> When performed stealthily, a takedown won't alert anyone and will reward Aiden with bonus experience. Using takedowns on criminals will increase Aiden's reputation as well.

I'm not sure how much more experience you get though.

If they don't know where you are that gives you a tactical advantage enabling you more room to maneuver around the area and plant traps or hack things. This in turn can make the game significantly easier. However you have the freedom to go "guns blazing" anytime you wish.

Comment: IIRC the stealth thing also works when employing a silent weapon like the silenced 1911, so they don't know you're there. But is there a difference between other enemies getting a knocked out companion back up and going looking for you or with them finding a body and reacting to that?

Comment: @ThomasJacobs The difference in terms of gameplay should be obvious. In terms of story [it makes no difference](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/172356/differences-in-lethal-vs-non-lethal-completion-of-missions).