# What advantages are there to lethal force?

Tags: watch-dogs-legion

I am playing with non-lethal munitions and hacking, but I recently came across an 'Amateur Hitman' armed with a Desert Eagle.

This made me wonder if there are any advantages to a lethal gameplay approach to the game?

[Referencing the first game, non-lethal gameplay rewarded more experience](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/259492/what-is-the-advantage-of-playing-non-lethally). So I wonder if this still holds true for Legion?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't played the game too much yet, but from what I know exp isn't really a thing anymore. All of the hacks are available IF you purchase with tech points (I believe) or have the character who can carry out the hack.

Using Lethal weapons is probably just better for the enemies that are harder to take down. At least that's how my experience has been so far.

And from what I know there aren't alternate endings to the game, so there shouldn't be consequences to the amount of people you kill.